# hightcharts - how to remove the box in the bottom

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm attaching an image of the hightchart.
Please let me know how can I remove the bottom middle box with the texts: 'Engaged','Unengaged' and how to remove the yAxis text in the line which says 1k.
[image]
Thanks

Also, how do I make it look like the next chart:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two items you are looking for are:

- legend.enabled ( http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#legend--enabled )
- yAxis.labels.style ( http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#yAxis-labels--style )

Here is a fiddle with these options set:

http://jsfiddle.net/YG88K/

Edit:

To answer your new question: not sure what you mean "make it look like this", if you mean curved lines that's handled by `chart.type='spline'` ( http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart--type )

Updated fiddle with curved line:

http://jsfiddle.net/YG88K/1/

Their documentation is excellent, I would highly recommend taking a look through their examples and API reference.

Comment: thx! , I've attached another picture, please help me make this chart look like the second picture, I can't figure it out.

Comment: thx, but that give the wanted result, the above result can get by having some error in the .Chart(...), which sounds wierd. when I mean look like this, I mean that the lines are curved like the example and have background color as you can see